# Spark best practice with big data volume

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Our Hadoop cluster is 20 nodes. 16 cores,128G memory / node.

We need to do a complex analysis against a log record dataset(hive) in HDFS, we have used Parquet+Snappy for compression and loaded 2 month logs to RDD, which is 0.5 billion records and takes approximately 40G in HDFS. SparkSql worked quiet well on it, from performance perspective.

We are basically doing something like this :

```
select host, ip from logs where t1<time<t2, 
select host, ip from logs where t3<time<t4,
select host, ip from logs where t5<time<t6,
select host, ip from logs where t7<time<t8,
```

then we merge the 4 set of the results and try to find out the Host/IP is active in the four time slots. The real situation is more complex, but for now, the example will do.

2 years log is almost 5 billion records, 300~G. We tried to load it all to RDD, SaprkSql works horribly slow, and obviously, we hit "out of memory" quite often(we allocated 30G mem for each Spark node). Just wondering is there any best practices for this sort of problem? e.g. keep the latest 2 months data for Spark while the older data gets processed in different means? Or Spark is probably not the right tool for this?

Comment: Which version of Spark do you use? Do you have access to Apache Flink? It handles high memory situations way better thant Spark. Another point seems to be your partitioning of the data. Seems you have 2,5 TB RAM in your cluster and 300G data. So try to distribute your calculations to all nodes.

Comment: Spark version : 1.5.2 , we have tried 1000, 1200, 1400 partitions, didn't make much difference.

Comment: if you are doing a key based aggregation and you have a key thats contains a lot of data then the number of partitions is irrelevant. because it is dominated by some large value sets.

Comment: @MatthiasKricke but is it normal 60G dataset 5-8 secs while 180G dataset 15 mins?

Comment: Unfortunately I cant give a blanket answer on this question. It highly depends on your data and algorithms. Did you see any hotspot issues? Where one machine is doing all the work for the 180g dataset?

Comment: We basically doing something like this :
select host, ip from logs where t1<time<t2, 
select host, ip from logs where t3<time<t4,
select host, ip from logs where t5<time<t6,
select host, ip from logs where t7<time<t8,
then we merge the 4 set of the results.

Comment: In your 600G scenario, whats the biggest time consumer of this steps? i guess its. Did you read the data once for the 4 comparisons or multiple times? did you checkpointed your RDD?

Comment: @MatthiasKricke actually, the query part takes the longest time. We read the data 1 once and carry out the comparisons.